# Take the text from EditText without a Button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm avoiding to use a button to retrieve the text of an EditText. It is possible to take the confirmation when an user just confirm from the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that takes an enter from the keyboard, and dismisses the soft keyboard from the screen when the user confirms:

```
    txtUserWord.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
            if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&
                    (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                inputWord = txtUserWord.getText().toString();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserWord.getWindowToken(),0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, Where can I use "inputWord" ? When I put something that needs some time to execute, the keyboard takes to disappear. I know why, but.. so Where can I put?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this previous post:

[Setting the Return key on the Android keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715098/setting-the-return-key-on-the-android-keyboard)